# Update marker position on google map without page load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to update the google map marker position in every 20 seconds which comes from database but it's doesn't work.

Code :

```
for (i = 0; i < purple.length; i++) {

    if (purple[i][1] == latitude && purple[i][2] == longitude) {
        nogreen = 1;
    }

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(purple[i][1], purple[i][2]),
            map : map,
            title : purple[i][0],
            data : purple[i][0],
            zoom : maxZoomService,
            icon : 'img/purple.png',
            shadow : 'img/purple.png'
        });

    setInterval(function () {
        position : new google.maps.LatLng(purple[i][1], purple[i][2]),
        marker.setPosition(position);
    }, 20000);
};
```

Is this correct or how can i do that ?

Comment: Where are you getting the updated position from the database?  Are you positive it is actually changing?

Comment: @geocodezip I've 2 pages code so i just put a part of Javascript code here which show a point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code here isn't valid javascript:

```
setInterval(function() {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(purple[i][1], purple[i][2]),
        marker.setPosition(position);
    }, 20000);
```

You want to do:

```
setInterval(function() {
        position = new google.maps.LatLng(purple[i][1], purple[i][2]);
        marker.setPosition(position);
    }, 20000);
```